# How to set custom locale in java ee?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, internationalization

I have an application that needs to set locale based on some url parameter.

I tried to set the `ResourceBundle` like this:

```
   Locale italian = new Locale("it", "IT");
   ResourceBundle bundle =
            PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("com.i18n.nl.MyResource",
                    italian);
    sessionBean.setBundle(bundle);

    request.getSession().setAttribute(Constants.SESSION_BEAN, sessionBean);
```

But, as my browser is English, it shows the English locale instead of the italian bundle resources.

Should I do anything else in my `.jsp` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to modify your JSP page to implement locale. Refer this link to implement locale in JSP. Hope it will help.

[link 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/819-3669/bnaxu/index.html).

[Link 2](http://www.wideskills.com/jsp/jsp-internationalization)

[Link 3](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html)